# Why are my If else statements not working?

Tags: if-statement

This program asks for a number from 1 to 12 and prints out the month and season correspondent to the input number, if the user types anything else than numbers from 1 to 12 an error message is displayed. It looks like the first if statement runs perfectly with its correspondent nested statements but the next else if statements wont work, try with 1, 2, and 12 and the program will work perfectly, but it doesn't with any other value, does anyone knows why this is happening?
Here's the program...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace  std;

int main() {

  int number;
  string season, month;

  cout << "Welcome! This program will provide the season of the year based on the month you enter, 1 corresponding to January, 2 for February and so on until 12 for December" << endl << endl;

  cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 12: ";
  cin >> number;

  if (number == 1 || 2 || 12)
  {
    if (number == 1)
    {
      month = "January";
      season = "winter";
    }
    else if (number == 2)
    {
      month = "February";
      season = "winter";
    }
    else if (number == 12)
    {
      month = "December";
      season = "winter";
    }
  }
  else if (number == 3 || 4 || 5)
  {
    if (number == 3)
    {
      month = "March";
      season = "spring";
    }
    else if (number == 4)
    {
      month = "April";
      season = "spring";
    }
    else if (number == 5)
    {
      month = "May";
      season = "spring";
    }
  }
  else if (number == 6 || 7 || 8 )
  {
    if (number == 6)
    {
      month = "June";
      season = "summer";
    }
    else if (number == 7)
    {
      month = "July";
      season = "summer";
    }
    else if (number == 8)
    {
      month = "August";
      season = "summer";
    }
  }
  else if (number == 9 || 10 || 11)
  {
    if (number == 9)
    {
      month = "September";
      season = "fall";
    }
    else if (number == 10)
    {
      month = "October";
      season = "fall";
    }
    else if (number == 11)
    {
      month = "November";
      season = "fall";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "You entered an ivalid value";
    return 0;
  }

  cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
  cout << "You entered " << number << ". " << month << " is the " << season << " season.";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `||` operator does not work how you are using it. That is, the statement `if (number == 1 || 2 || 12)` is likely being converted into boolean values:

`number == 1`

`2`

`12`

So imaging you are forcing each of those values into a boolean representation. There's probably a more exact way of explaining this though.

The fix is likely to do this:

`if (number == 1 || number == 2 || number == 12)`

etc.